# python dictionary update method

Tags: python, dictionary, variables

I have a list string tag.

I am trying to initialize a dictionary with the key as the tag string and values as the array index.

```
for i, ithTag in enumerate(tag):
    tagDict.update(ithTag=i)
```

The above returns me {'ithTag': 608}  *608 is the 608th index*

My problem is that while the i is being interpreted as a variable, Python is treating the "ithTag" as a string instead of a variable.

I'm confused, it is kind of hard to google these kind of specific questions.  I hope I worded the title of this question correctly,

Thanks!

Comment: This is a nearly upvotable question. I think only the chosen answer is worse than [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/179005/131120). Mind to change or explain the reasons behind choosing the for-loop answer?

Comment: I chose that one because Jerub answered first; and I just marked it right away. Also coming from a C#/Java background, Jerub's answer looks more familiar to me and I liked his explanation of why .update() didn't work for me.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

You actually want to do this:

```
for i, tag in enumerate(tag):
    tagDict[tag] = i
```

The .update() method is used for updating a dictionary using another dictionary, not for changing a single key/value pair.

Answer (score 18):

If you want to be clever:

```
tagDict.update(map(reversed, enumerate(tag)))
```

Thanks to Brian for the update. This is apparently ~5% faster than the iterative version.

(EDIT: Thanks saverio for pointing out my answer was incorrect (now fixed). Probably the most efficient/Pythonic way would be Torsten Marek's answer, slightly modified:

```
tagDict.update((t, i) for (i,t) in enumerate(tag))
```

)

Comment: Actually, update() can take a sequence directly, so there's no need to construct an intermediate dict.  Doing tagDict.update(enumerate(tag)) is actually slightly (~5%) quicker than the iterative version.

Comment: The keys of `tagDict` have to be the elements of `tag`. Use `tagDict.update(map(reversed, enumerate(tag)))`, in fact the functional equivalent of Torsten Marek's answer.

Comment: @Claudiu, because, as already saverio mentioned, `tagDict.update(enumerate(tag))` makes indexes as dict keys, while they must be values

Answer (score 12):

It's a one-liner:

```
tagDict = dict((t, i) for i, t in enumerate(tag))
```

Comment: I think this should be the accepted answer - it is more clear what is going on here, no side-effects to worry about.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is what you want to do:

```
d = {}
for i, tag in enumerate(ithTag):
   d[tag] = i
```

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
tagDict[ithTag] = i
```

Answer (score 2):

I think what you want  is this:

```
for i, ithTag in enumerate(tag):
    tagDict.update({ithTag: i})
```