# python: adding to a dict gives error

Tags: python, dictionary

```
playlist = {}
playlist.update(position, title)
```

here position and title are two strings. 
I am getting the following error: 
TypeError: update expected at most 1 arguments, got 2

could some please help?
thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can only update a dict with another dictionnary (you could also give it an iterable of tuples (key, value) :

```
playlist = {item1 : value1}
playlist.update({position : title})
print playlist

>>> {item1 : value1, position : title}

playlist.update([(item2, value2),])
print playlist
>>> {item1 : value1, position : title, item2: value2}
```

Comment: thanks a lot. also update would add to the dict or would it just replace the dict?

Comment: as its name suggests, it would add the elements to the dict. But you could have tried this by yourself.

Comment: @Sunny : it will update the content of the initial dict as my edit shows it.

Comment: FWIW, „You can only update a dict with another dictionnary“ is not strictly true: `update` will also accept an iterable of pairs. For example, `playlist.update([(position, title)])`.

Comment: @PetrViktorin : right, I updated my answer with you suggestion

Answer (score 5):

`dict.update()` expects a dictionary:

```
playlist = {}
playlist.update({position: title})
```

If you just want to set a single key, don't use update - use bracket notation instead:

```
playlist[position] = title
```

Answer (score 3):

You must pass a dict as argument:

```
>>> a = {}
>>> a.update({'a': 1})
>>> a
{'a': 1}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
playlist[position] = title
```

This is the way you should do this. Update is handy when you try to copy elements of one dict into another one.

Answer (score 2):

Use this:

```
playlist[position] = title
```

`playlist.update` is to be used with a dictionary as an argument:

```
playlist.update({position: title})
```

Comment: thanks a lot. also update would add to the dict or would it just replace the dict?

Comment: @Sunny `update` would add new items to the dict and update existing.

Answer (score 0):

You have already got the answer. Posting a few good links:

http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#dict.update

[python dictionary update method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/173290/python-dictionary-update-method)

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/dictionary_update.htm