# Python dictionary didn't update

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

After update dict over iteration dict keeps only last iterating pair.

SAMPLE:

```
# DICTIONARY PROBLEM
class Dict_ator(object):
    def __init__(self, str, int):
        self.string = str
        self.integer = int

boogeyman = []
i = 1
for char in "boogeyman" :
    boogeyman.append( Dict_ator(char, i) )
    i += 1

dictonary = {}
for b in boogeyman :
    dictonary.update( s = b.string, i = b.integer )
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: What output do you want?

Comment: This is unrelated to the issue you were having, but it's generally a bad idea to use the names `str` and `int` as variable names (as you're doing in `Dict_ator.__init__`). That's because they're the names of built-in objects, and it can be very surprising to find that they do something else some of the time. It's not too bad when that's in a function's local namespace, but it can lead to very confusing bugs if you ever do it at module level.

Comment: possible duplicate of [python dictionary update method](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/173290/python-dictionary-update-method)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are setting the same keys over and over again:

```
dictonary.update( s = b.string, i = b.integer )
```

By using keywords, you are setting two keys; `s` and `i`; the very definition of a dictionary is that they map keys to values, where keys are unique.

If you wanted to set different key-value combinations for each element in your loop, set different keys. For example, using `b.string` for each key, and `b.integer` for the values, pass both in as a tuple:

```
dictonary.update((b.string, b.integer))
```

or just set the key-value directly using assignment:

```
dictonary[b.string] = b.integer
```

You replace that whole loop with a dict comprehension:

```
dictionary = {b.string: b.integer for b in boogeyman}
```

Your first loop could be simplified using [`enumerate()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate) with a start value of `1`, and a list comprehension:

```
boogeyman = [Dict_ator(char, i)) for i, char in enumerate("boogeyman", 1)]
```

If you don't need the `Dict_ator` objects, you can just use that same `enumerate()` loop to build the dictionary:

```
dictionary = {char: i for i, char in enumerate('boogeyman', 1)}
```

Swap the integer and character components around if you wanted your dictionary to map the other way.

Comment: Or everything in one line: `dict((s, i) for i, s in enumerate("boogeyman", 1))`.

Comment: Thank you very much...your answer enlightened me. :)

Answer (score 1):

One line may solve your problem:

```
>>> {i: c for i, c in enumerate("boogeyman", 1)}
{1: 'b', 2: 'o', 3: 'o', 4: 'g', 5: 'e', 6: 'y', 7: 'm', 8: 'a', 9: 'n'}
```

Comment: Of course, what you have now is essentially a 1-based list, which is of questionable value.

Comment: That is what the OP wanted.

By itself yes. But you may need it for the next step to update for the next word or such.

Answer (score 1):

This works

```
class Dict_ator(object):
    def __init__(self, str, int):
        self.string = str
        self.integer = int

boogeyman = []
i = 1
for char in "boogeyman" :
    boogeyman.append( Dict_ator(char, i) )
    i += 1

dictonary = {}
for b in boogeyman :
    dictonary[b.string] = b.integer
```

Your `Dict_ator`... only for storing one character and associated position... seems like too much. Also, why aren't you in a position to add directly to dict, like that

```
dictonary = {}
i = 1
for char in "boogeyman" :
    dictonary[char] = i
```

simple, uh?

Comment: It works, too. Thanks. However, I found the error in your code : dictonary != dictionary. Ha!